# Openshift mysql clustering

Tags: mysql, openshift, master-slave

I am playing around with Openshift and I was trying to create a master-slave configuration using mysql 5.5 but I am not able to do it.
Once I added the mysql5.5 cartridge I can't add another similar cartridge (the slave one).

Can anyone help me please? Is it possible to obtain master-slave configuration with mysql5.5 using two different cartridges?

If not why?

I mean, I can create a "scalable app" but I can't create a cluster for the DB?!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not use the standard MySQL cartridges for this. This article describes how to set up master slave replication  on openshift: https://blog.openshift.com/cloudy-with-a-chance-of-data-master-slave-database-replication-on-openshift/

Comment: Many thanks! I have already tried with that post but there are a couple of problems. The first one is that those cartridges have MYSQL5.1 and not 5.5. Furthermore I am not able to complete the step 4.2 because I got the message "access denied...". Basically I can't access to mysql using command line. I have also tried using port-forward but nothing. I was wondering why! Using the provided cartridge for both mysql5.5 and 5.1 I can easily get access.  Have you ever tried?

Comment: "Access denied" smells like permissions (GRANT) problems.  Are _you_ being denied?  Or is the _slave_ being denied?

Comment: I have just tried to access using the usual "mysql -u <user> -p. And then inserting the password of the DB, but it does not work! I've also tried this: "mysql -u ${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME} \
 -p${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD} --host \
${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}" but I have the same problem for both master and slave DB!!